# is the computed Hoteling's T square correct?

Tags: python, hotelling-t2

I am testing the Hoteling Tsquare test on a toy example using scikit learn.
I am following the description in this [this link](http://wiki.eigenvector.com/index.php?title=T-Squared_Q_residuals_and_Contributions).

Is the size of the obtained Tsquare values correct? Shouldn't it be a simple vector of size 13?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import preprocessing

hald_text = """Y       X1      X2      X3      X4
    78.5    7       26      6       60
    74.3    1       29      15      52
    104.3   11      56      8       20
    87.6    11      31      8       47
    95.9    7       52      6       33
    109.2   11      55      9       22
    102.7   3       71      17      6
    72.5    1       31      22      44
    93.1    2       54      18      22
    115.9   21      47      4       26
    83.8    1       40      23      34
    113.3   11      66      9       12
    109.4   10      68      8       12
    """
    hald = np.loadtxt(hald_text.splitlines(), skiprows=1)


pca_sklearn=PCA(n_components=4)
data=hald

data=preprocessing.scale(data)

output=pca_sklearn.fit_transform(data)
output=pca_sklearn.transform(data.reshape(-1,1))

hoteling_metric=data.dot(pca_sklearn.components_.T).dot(np.diag(1/pca_sklearn.explained_variance_)).dot(pca_sklearn.components_).dot(data.T)
print(hoteling_metric)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `data.reshape(-1,1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of reflexion, it seems that the Tsquare given by these lines of code lies simply in the diagonal of the matrix. The other values doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, your conclusion is correct that the diagonals of your result equal the Hotelling's $T^2$ values for each sample. However, it took me a while to figure that out. So I'm posting my own answer in case it helps anyone else who is trying to calculate Hotelling's $T^2$ values using Python.

According to the page you linked from wiki.eigenvector.com, "[Hotelling's $T^2$ values represent a measure of the variation of each sample within the model](http://wiki.eigenvector.com/index.php?title=T-Squared_Q_residuals_and_Contributions)".  The formula given on that page (copied below) is for calculating the $T^2$ value for one sample:

$$ T_i^2 = t_i\lambda^{-1}t_i^T = x_iP_k\lambda^{-1}P_k^Tx_i^T $$

To get $T^2$ values for all 13 samples in your data, you can use this formula on each sample.  Here's how it looks in Python, starting with your data:

```
data=preprocessing.scale(data)

output=pca_sklearn.fit_transform(data)

loadings_p = pca_sklearn.components_.T
eigenvalues = pca_sklearn.explained_variance_

hotelling_t2s = np.array([xi.dot(loadings_p)
                            .dot(np.diag(eigenvalues ** -1))
                            .dot(loadings_p.T)
                            .dot(xi.T)
                          for xi in data])
```